# decorator python library hide the kwargs inside args

Tags: python, decorator, keyword-argument

I got a pretty weird behaviour with the decorator library which is explained in the next code:

```
from decorator import decorator    

@decorator
def wrap(f, a, *args, **kwargs):
    print 'Decorator:', a, args, kwargs
    return f(a, *args, **kwargs)

def mywrap(f):
    def new_f(a, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'Home made decorator:', a, args, kwargs
        return f(a, *args, **kwargs)
    return new_f

@wrap
def funcion(a, b, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

@mywrap
def myfuncion(a, b, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

funcion(1, b=2)
myfuncion(1, b=2)
```

The execution of this script prints:

```
$ python /tmp/test.py 
Decorator: 1 (2,) {}
Home made decorator: 1 () {'b': 2}
```

'decorator' hides the kwargs inside the args, how can I solve this without using a "home made" decorator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because you *call* the function with `b=2` does not make `b` a keyword argument; `b` is a positional argument in the original function. If there were no argument named `b` and you specified `b=2`, *then* `b` would become a keyword argument.

`decorator`'s behavior is actually the most correct; the wrapper it generates has the same signature as `funcion()`, whereas the wrapper made by your "homemade" decorator does not have `b` as a named argument. The "homemade" wrapper "incorrectly" puts `b` in `kwargs` because the signature of `myfuncion()`, which makes it clear that `b` is not a keyword arg, is hidden from the caller.

Preserving the function signature is a feature, not a bug, in `decorator`.