# Issue with decorator and keyword arguments

Tags: python, decorator

I'm using the [decorator](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) module to decorate some functions. I want the decorator to be quite general, so I'm allowing it to have any number of arguments and keyword arguments (as long as there are more than two arguments):

```
from decorator import decorator

def wrap(f):
    return decorator(_wrap, f)

def _wrap(function, t, f, *args, **kwargs):

    print 't=', t
    print 'f=', f
    print 'args=', args
    print 'kwargs=', kwargs

@wrap
def read(a, b, c=False, d=True):
    pass

read(1, 2, d=True)
```

The issue is that the above return:

```
t= 1
f= 2
args= (False, True)
kwargs= {}
```

but the `False` and `True` come from `c=` and `d=`, so shouldn't they be in `kwargs`, i.e.:

```
t= 1
f= 2
args= (,)
kwargs= {'c':False, 'd':True}
```

?

Answer (score 2):

`c` and `d` *are* positional arguments. Their names are included in the function object's metadata (because you use `decorator`, it's also preserved on the wrapper) and therefore you can refer to their names when calling the function, but they're still positional arguments and specifying them by their names merely leads to them being put into the correct positions in `args`. And it works as expected, so why is it an issue?

Comment: Say I wrap two functions, ``def read(a, b, c=False, d=True):`` and ``def read2(a, b, d=False, c=True):``, are you saying I can't know what c and d are inside _wrap? Imagine if ``d=`` was ``verbose=``, and that I want to print out information inside _wrap only if ``verbose=True`` - can I do that?

Comment: @astrofrog: You can (if you really need to) infer it from the argspec (see the `inspect` stdlib module). But if it's information for the wrapper, perhaps the wrapper should explicitly take it as an argument (and potentially pass it on to the wrapped function)?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, check this other post talking about the same issue [decorator python library hide the kwargs inside args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700432/decorator-python-library-hide-the-kwargs-inside-args) (and giving the same answer as delnan)